# ServletClassLoader cannot call getClassLoader in Spring Boot

Tags: java, servlets, spring-boot, servletcontextlistener

I have a `ServletContextListener` that I am initializing through Spring Boot. Normally, the listener would get the `ClassLoader` instance from the `ServletContext`. However, because it is being added to the container via Spring Boot, the `ServletContextListener` cannot call the `getClassLoader()` method. (It must be initialized via web.xml, web-fragment.xml, or the `@WebListener` annotation.)

So, what's the best way to get the proper `ClassLoader` instance to the `ServletContextListener`?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with two potential solutions to this problem:

1. Get a `ClassLoader` instance from an injected `ResourceLoader`. I decided not to take this approach because it returned Spring Boot's `ClassLoader` instance and not the web container's.
2. Inject the `ServletContext` instance into the bean creation method, and pass that to the `ServletContextListener` constructor. This works for Tomcat, which implements the restrictions by wrapping the `ServletContext` and overriding methods to throw exceptions. By injecting, I was able to use an unwrapped version that did not implement the restrictions. This may not work on other containers.